# How to get the name or signature of the current method into an NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, uikit

Example: I have a method `-myFooBarMethod:withFoo:bar:moreFoo:` and inside the implementation of that method I want to dynamically get the name of it, like `@"-myFooBarMethod:withFoo:bar:moreFoo:` into an NSString. No hard-typing of the method signature.

I feel that this has to do something with selectors. How could I get the name of the current method (the one that executes the code) as NSString?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Every method call also passes two hidden arguments: an `id` named `self` and a `SEL` named `_cmd`. You can use `NSStringFromSelector` to convert the method selector to an NSString:

```
NSStringFromSelector(_cmd);
```

Comment: You can also use the **`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`** macro, which the preprocessor replaces with a C string (char*) of the method name. It also works for C functions.

Comment: I was not aware there was a macro called `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`.  I love it.  Now I just have to find a reason to use it in my code somewhere...

Answer (score 17):

Use `__func__`. This is a C string, so for an NSString, use `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__func__]`.

This has two advantages over `_cmd`:

1. It works in C functions and C++ methods as well as Objective-C methods. (In fact, `__func__` is required to exist by C99.)
2. In Objective-C methods, it includes the method type (class method vs. instance method) and the class name as well as the selector. For example, `"-[MyView drawRect:]"`.

Answer (score 8):

As an example of where this sort of thing is useful: This is a template for NSLog messages that I use:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@: %@", NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), @"A Message");
```

This dumps the class and the method to the console when logging.

Answer (score 1):

As per Martin's answer, but you might also like to read the [Objective C 2.0 Runtime](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) information.

Playing in the guts like this tends to lead to hard to manage code, however.

Comment: There are times it is valid, though.

Comment: Apple's own Developer Examples use it for logging like this: `NSLog(@"%@ received %@", self, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));`